# When to make thesis available for public access?

Tags: publications, thesis

I have recently finished my thesis and submitted to both university and national thesis center.

However, it is not online yet (probably there are many thesis pending). Should I wait for the thesis center to make it available or can I just put it to my website?

Comment: What country and what field?

Answer (score 2):

Unless your university has a policy that explicitly forbids it (which would be very strange), you should feel free to post your thesis online as soon as it has been officially submitted and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my advisor when I should put my thesis on arXiv and he said I should do it after my defense, but not earlier. (And I complied.) It seems to be a standard practice (at least in theoretical physics).

If there is demand, (very likely) you can mail your thesis privately (I did a few times). But putting it publicly may give some risk:

- it could look as if you have already defended it,
- in the case of failing (which, depends on country and procedures, may be possible or unlikely) it is kind of awkward.

Plus, the standard caveats: ask your advisor, check your institution policy etc.

Comment: I forgot to add, I have already defended it and it is accepted by the commitee

Comment: So, just put it (unless there are direct rules against it). If possible, I *really* recommend arXiv (or if not relevant - another repository). The chances are your website will be gone in matter of years (or decades).